# With makecell the text dimension is reduced

Tags: fontsize, makecell

I added the `makecell` package in order to insert a line break within a column of `tabular` environment.

Everything perfect and smooth except for the shrinkage of the text dimension:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{subscript}
\usepackage{xunicode,xltxtra,url,parskip}   %other packages for formatting
\usepackage[big]{layaureo}              
\usepackage{titlesec}                   
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}             
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{eqparbox,array}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{makecell}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{L{mylhead}p{0.95\textwidth-\mylheadwd}}
\textsc{\thead[cr]{Prof.~Dr.\\A.~Einstein}} & \thead[cl]{Physics Department\\University of the Universe}\\
& e-mail: \href{mailto:einstein@phy.uniun.un}{einstein@phy.uniun.un}\\\multicolumn{2}{c}{} \\
\textsc{\thead[cr]{Prof.\\M.~Curie}} & \thead[cl]{Department of Physics \\University of the Universe}\\
& e-mail: \href{mailto:m.curie@phy.un}{m.curie@phy.un}\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

NB: I used `12pt` in the `documentclass`.
The dimensions of what is inside `\thead` is smaller than what is outside (the email address for example).

Is `makecell` resetting what specified in the preamble?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`\thead` (not `\makecell`) sets the  font size to `\footnotesize` for some reason. Add to your preamble

```
\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalsize\scshape}
```

*Note:* The `\scshape` command is in this code because the O.P. contains `\textsc{\thead{...}}` commands

Comment: `\scshape` is not even necessary

Comment: @Szczypawka: But the the image  in the O.P.'s post uses small caps!

Comment: Right. I didn't notice. But it's nice to add it as a comment to make the answer more general...

Comment: Right. I didn't notice. But it's nice to add it as a comment to make the answer more general...

Comment: Thanks for the solution! It works! Although I had to remove `\scshape`. It might be worth printing the command without this. Is there any reason this is not the default behaviour by the way?

Comment: What would I do, if I wanted the `thead` font size to be identical to the remainder of the table (i.e. sometimes `normalsize` and other times `scriptsize`)?

Comment: Do you mean, depending on the table? e.g. some tables with \normal size, some with \small, some with \scriptsize? Each time you want to change the heat font size from the default, use the relevant command  as in the answer, inside a group, to make it local.