# Get makecell thead to emulate font size of table environment?

Tags: tables, fontsize, makecell

I have a table defined like this:

```
\begin{table}[]
\tiny
```

It contains a table header in bold with a line break between words.

```
\textbf{\thead{word1 \\ word2}}
```

I added this to my pre-amble as per [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/375884/69025), because `\makecell` or `\thead` sets the font size to `\footnotesize`.

```
\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalsize}
```

How do I get `\makecell` and `\thead` to just emulate the table environment? Sometimes my tables use font size `\normalsize` and other times `\tiny` and other font sizes.

Comment: you have not provided a test file but I would assume `\renewcommand\theadfont{}` does the right thing if you don't want the command to change the font

Answer (score 5):

If you don't want the command to change the font then

```
 \renewcommand\theadfont{}
```